# Using Enterprise Library's ExecuteSprocAccessor method with generics

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, enterprise-library, generics

I am trying to use one class to handle all of my CRUD on the database by using the ExecuteSprocAccessor method of the .NET Enterprise Library with generics.  In my data layer, I was trying something like this:

```
public static class CRUDDatabase
{
    private static Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ITS");

    public static T SelectSingle<T>(string sprocName, int id)
    {
        return db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<T>(sprocName, id).First();
    }
}
```

However, I get a build error on the return line in the SelectSingle() method that states:

> *'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TResult' in the generic
>   type or method
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseExtensions.ExecuteSprocAccessor(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database,
>   string, params object[])'*

The idea behind the SelectSingle() method is that you pass in the stored procedure name and the record id of the object you want from the database.  Eventually I would have SelectAll(), Update(), Delete(), etc. The parameters in those methods would be different, but you get the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.

After reading that error, I am beginning to think this may be impossible, but does anyone know if this can work?  Also, my fields in the database match 1:1 with the fields in my classes, so that is why I am not specifying any mappers.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is telling you what's wrong: it's expecting a type that's got a zero-argument public constructor on it. All you've handed it is T, which it can't make any guarantees on, so it won't compile.

You need to add a generic constraint to limit the types T can be. Luckily, that's trivially easy:

```
public static T SelectSingle<T>(string sprocName, int id)    
    where T : new()  // <---- here's the constraint
{
    return db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<T>(sprocName, id).First();    
}
```

That tells the compiler "Any type passed here *must* have a zero-argument constructor.