# Using Enterprise Library's ExecuteSprocAccessor retrieve list<string>

Tags: c#, string, oracle, list, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise Library to connect to Oracle DataBase. I am using ExecuteSprocAccessor to retrieve data.

My problem is that I need to retrieve a List

```html
public List<string> Process() 
        {
            Database db = readConfig.ReadWebConfig();
            string Procedure = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GET_MAILS_PROCESO_CONTABLES"];
            string SP_NAME = package + "." + Procedure;
            using (DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand(SP_NAME))
            {
                dbCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                OracleParameter oraPara1 = new OracleParameter("CURSOR", OracleType.Cursor);
                oraPara1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add(oraPara1);
                object[] param = readConfig.ParametertoObj(dbCommand);
                List<string> result = db.ExecuteSprocAccessor<string>(SP_NAME, param).ToList<string>();
                return result;
            }
        }
```

I have the following error

*'string' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TResult' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseExtensions.ExecuteSprocAccessor(Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database, string, params object[])'*

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083355/using-enterprise-librarys-executesprocaccessor-method-with-generics) link, but it does not help too much.

How can I retrieve a List?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am having the same issue currently and I agree that the referenced link is not really helpful for my situation.